# Jquery slide in effect 100% width

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

First, here is my problem: [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1utpq0ud/). I want to set a fixed width to the `login` Container. When I hover it, the `login` container should get 100% width. It's working fine, but I don't want to see the content of the container. The content should be shown when the container slides in. How can I fix this problem?

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

  $('#login').mouseover(function(){
    $('#login').animate({"width":"100%"});
  });

});
```

```css
*{
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
}

#login{
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  width: 20px;
  background: rgba(0,0,0,0.45);

  padding: 20px 0px;
  text-align: center;
}

.loginRow{
  visibility: hidden;
  visibility: visible;
}

.loginRow:first-child{
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.loginLabel{
  display: inline-block;
  width: 150px;
  text-align: left;

  color: #29333D;
}

.loginInput{
  color: #29333D;
  background-color: transparent;
  border:none;
  border-top: 3px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 3px solid #8F9F87;
  width: 200px;
}

.loginInput:hover{
  border-bottom-color: #AFB79A;
}

.loginInput:focus{
  border-bottom-color: #AFB79A;
}

.loginInput::-webkit-input-placeholder { /* WebKit, Blink, Edge */
    color:    #A9A9A9;
}
.loginInput:-moz-placeholder { /* Mozilla Firefox 4 to 18 */
   color:    #A9A9A9;
}
.loginInput::-moz-placeholder { /* Mozilla Firefox 19+ */
   color:    #A9A9A9;
}
.loginInput:-ms-input-placeholder { /* Internet Explorer 10-11 */
   color:    #A9A9A9;
}
.loginInput:placeholder-shown { /* Standard (https://drafts.csswg.org/selectors-4/#placeholder) */
  color:    #A9A9A9;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="login">
      <div class="loginRow">
        <a class="loginLabel">Benutzername</a>
        <input class="loginInput" type="text" placeholder="Benutzername"/>
      </div>
      <div class="loginRow">
        <a class="loginLabel">Passwort</a>
        <input class="loginInput" type="password" placeholder="Passwort"/>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Here is an example:

First.

[image]

When hover the container it slides in.

[image]

Comment: You need to be more specific than 'looks ugly'. What behaviour do you want to have/not have?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I don't want to see the content. The content of the container should slide in.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Given your comment defining what you want to actually do:

> I don't want to see the content. The content of the container should slide in.

You can achieve this by keeping the `div` at `100%` width and animating it's `left` position. Try this:

```
#login{
  left: -98%;
  /* other styles... */
}
```

```js
$('#login').mouseover(function(){
    $('#login').animate({ "left": "0" });
});
```

[**Updated fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/1utpq0ud/4/)

You could then take this one step further and toggle the animation when the element is hovered in and out, like this:

```
$('#login').hover(function(e) {
    var leftPos = e.type == 'mouseenter' ? '0' : '-98%';
    $('#login').animate({ "left": leftPos });
});
```

[**Example fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/1utpq0ud/6/)

Comment: Thanks for the answer! It's nearly perfect, but how can I set a fixed width at the beginning? Now it's 2% but I want a width of 20px.

Comment: You can't do that reliably as the full width of the div will be 100%. Therefore you need to use a -% width on the `left` property as you don't know what the actual width of the element is, as it may be 500px on one screen and 2000px on another.

Comment: Ok, because I wanted to add an arrow image at the 20px width. But thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

You can set opacity like following:

```
a, input{
  opacity:0;
}
```

And JQuery.

```
$('#login').mouseover(function(){
    $('#login').animate({"width":"100%"});
    $('a').css("opacity","1");
    $('input').css("opacity","1");
  });
```

**[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1utpq0ud/5/)**

**Edit:**

As per you edit you can do following way:

CSS:

```
#login{
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  background: rgba(0,0,0,0.45);
  padding: 20px 0px;
  text-align: center;

  left:-95%;
  width: 100%;
}
```

And JQuery:

```
$('#login').mouseover(function(){
    $('#login').animate({"left":"0"});
  });
```

**[Updated Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1utpq0ud/7/)**

Second method is also implemented by @RoryMcCrossan.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Ohh man. You already did it. Sorry I have not read that.

Comment: Thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 0):

Add a fixed height to the `div#login` and use `hover` for a nice in and out effect:

**CSS:**

```
#login{
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  width: 20px;
  height: 100px;
  background: rgba(0,0,0,0.45);
  padding: 20px 0px;
  text-align: center;
}

.loginRow{
  display: none;
}
```

**JS:**

```
$('#login').hover(
    function(){
        $('#login .loginRow').stop(true,false).fadeIn(400);
        $('#login').stop(true,false).animate({"width":"100%"});
    },
    function(){
        $('#login .loginRow').stop(true,false).fadeOut(200);
        $('#login').stop(true,false).animate({"width":"20px"});
    }
);
```

JS Fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/1utpq0ud/9/).